# app.vote(1, {from: web3.eth.accounts[0] }) not working

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-deployment, ethereum-wallet-dapp, truffle-console

I am following a tutorial from Dapp University about building Election Smart Contract. When I run this command in the console:

```
app.vote(1, {from: web3.eth.accounts[0] })
```

I get the following error:

```
Thrown: <Error: The send transaction "from" field must be defined!
```

I know that "web3.eth.accounts" has been depreciated and I have tried a few ways to solve it but so far no luck.

Comment: What version of web3.js are you using?

Comment: @goodvibration version 1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

How many arguments does the `vote` method take?
In `web3.js` the smart contract method's arguments are interpreted first,
and the last argument is expected to be transaction options such as:
`{ from, gas, gasPrice }`

If you are supplying a different number of arguments than is expected,
`web3.js` will try to find the `from` field from an argument where it's not present.

Also, you can try adding this line to your code, to make sure it still works and has not been removed yet.
`console.log('Account 0', web3.eth.accounts[0])`

Answer (score 0):

that error is because you pass account= `''` .(in the from:)
i think is your web3 version(can you check the version in console with "web3.version")
and with web3 1.x.x can you try : `web3.currentProvider.selectedAddress` to get the address.